# How to get OEM ID on a WIndows Phone Device?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When windows phone user search any app in Store, WP device will connect to a link like this :

> http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com/v8/catalog/apps?os=8.0.10512.0&cc=US&oc=&lang=vi-VN&hw=469838850&dm=Virtual&oemId=NOKIA&moId=&chunkSize=50

I want to get the DM value and OEMId value, how can I do that? 
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is OEMID (it looks like DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer) and DM, but for retrieving information about the device you should use classes from this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info(v=vs.105).aspx namespace